# Why is bar blacklisted in pylint

Tags: python, django, pylint

I have an error while linting my django project with pylint.
Pylint shows an error while linting my django project "C0102: Black listed name "bar" (blacklisted-name)"

It's correct that I have a function called bar, but why is this name blacklisted?
I don't know of a built-in with that name.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PyLint has a default list of names that shouldn't be used for variables: `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `toto`, `tutu`, and `tata`. I think the reason that `bar` is on this list is that it's often used along with `foo` and `baz` as a "jokey" name for a variable in example or throwaway code.

The list of blacklisted names is changeable via the [`bad-names` option](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/stable/technical_reference/features.html#basic-checker). You can also find more information on disabling certain checks at these links:

- http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/stable/faq.html#message-control
- https://www.codependentcodr.com/disabling-pylint-messages.html

Comment: This is kind of dumb because there's nothing wrong with using `bar` in *hyper-generic* examples. It's not any worse than `x`, `y`, `f`, `g`, ...

Comment: @MateenUlhaq It may be dumb, but that's how PyLint does it.

Comment: I was using bar as in a bar in a bar chart, and pylint's nags lead me here.